# What does it mean when you assign int to a variable in Python?

Tags: python, variables, int, type-conversion

i.e. `x = int`

I understand that this will make `x` an integer if it is not already one, but I'd like to understand the process behind this. In particular, I'd like to know what `int` is (as opposed to `int()`). I know that `int()` is a function, but I'm not sure what `int` is. Links to documentation about `int` would be helpful since I couldn't find any.

Comment: "I understand that this will make x an integer if it is not already one" - it won't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Imagine you had a function called `func`

```
def func():
    print("hello from func")
    return 7
```

If you then assigned `func` to `x` you are assigning the function *itself* to `x` **not** the result of the call

```
x = func # note: no ()
x() # calls func()
y = x() # y is now 7
```

You're looking at a very similar thing with `int` in this context.

```
x = int
y = x('2') # y is now 2
```

Comment: up vote for such plain good example! I never noticed it though!

Comment: I would also suggest that for fundamental things like int/float etc, this is a really bad idea. It just reduces the readability of your code.

Answer (score 7):

`x = int` will not make `x` into an integer.  `int` is the integer type.  Doing `x = int` will set `x` to the value of the `int` type.  Loosely speaking, `x` will become an "alias" for the integer type.

If you *call* the int type on something, like `int('2')`, it will convert what you give into an integer, if it can.  If you assign the result of that call to a variable, it will set that variable to the integer value you got from calling `int`.  So setting `x = int('2')` will set `x` to 2.

You should read [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/tutorial) to understand how types, variables, and calling work in Python.

Comment: Nice question followed by a beautiful answer

Comment: Is it something similar to "*typedef*" in C ?

Comment: @d-coder: Only very, very loosely. In Python, types (and functions, and pretty much everything) are first-class objects, just like integers and strings and lists. So, Python doesn't _need_ anything like `typedef`. All you're doing is creating another name for the same object. The fact that the object happens to be a type is irrelevant; it's no different than `x = 2` creates another name for the `2` object.